# Don't need email, while registration Ion_auth

Tags: php, ion-auth

is there any way (probably is - in ion_auth config), how to do not need email, while registration? - I need just username and password :)

Answer (score 0):

In the file `/application/config/ion_auth.php` set the following

```
// Email Activation for registration
$config['email_activation'] = FALSE;
```

This is on line #101 in my file. Should be close to the same in yours.